# How to get the user a response if Lambda times out?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have a lambda function that subscribes a user to a newsletter via an API, but I'm wondering how to send an error message to the user in case the Lambda times out waiting for the newsletter API.

Is there are way to say:

`if (timeout) { return 500 }`

What if it's a lambda@edge? Does the timeout then just drop back to my origin server?

Answer (score 3):

The code samples on [GitHub - stelligent/cloudformation-custom-resources](https://github.com/stelligent/cloudformation-custom-resources) include some examples of aborting a Lambda function when the available time expires.

The Python example includes the code:

```
# Setup alarm for remaining runtime minus a second
signal.alarm((context.get_remaining_time_in_millis() / 1000) - 1)

def timeout_handler(_signal, _frame):
    '''Handle SIGALRM'''
    raise Exception('Time exceeded')

signal.signal(signal.SIGALRM, timeout_handler)
```